# Edit text in columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Input :

```
df['Price'].head()
```

Output
:

```
         col
    ---------------
    0    35.41 Lakhs
    1    47.59 Crore
    2    50.50 Lakhs
    3    38.44 Lakhs

    Name: Price, dtype: object
```

I need the output as
:

```
         col
    ----------
    0    35.41 
    1    0.4759 
    2    50.50 
    3    38.44
```

ie, the 'Lakhs' and 'Crore' tags to be removed and the lakh figure to be turned into crore in the column.

What can be the code to achive this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried? What did not work? Please include your attempts. SO is not a free code writing service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract the numbers by using [`.str.extract()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with regex of floating point numbers, as follows:

```
df['Price'] = df['Price'].str.extract(r'(\d+(?:.\d+)?)')
```

This regex `(\d+(?:.\d+)?)` works for both numbers with and without decimal points (integer and floating point numbers).

Result:

```
print(df)

   Price
0  35.41
1  47.59
2  50.50
3  38.44
```

Comment: It works !
Thankyou !

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> df.replace({'Price': {'Lakhs': '* 1', 'Crore': '/ 100'}},
               regex=True)['Price'].apply(eval)

0    35.41
1    47.59
2    50.50
3    38.44
Name: Price, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Hi thanks for replying but i am getting this error        

File "<ipython-input-307-9ab7c83d332b>", line 1, in <module>
    df.replace({'Price': {'Lakhs': '* 1', 'Crore': '/ 100'}},regex=True)['Price'].apply(eval)

  File "C:\Users\DELL\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 4138, in apply
   mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
  File "pandas\_libs\lib.pyx", line 2467, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer
  File "<string>", line 1
    3 / 100s
           ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: You added a `s` at the end of `'/ 100s'`...